# .net core Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider ISO-8859-1 Error

Tags: .net-core

I want to add some servis reference in .net core 3.1 application. I can add below wsdl adress, at .net framework in 'Add Service Reference' tool and there is no problem and no error.

But I take below error in .net core 'Add-> Service Reference' tool.

I am using Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider.

> An error occurred while attempting to find services at 'https://.....com.tr/web_services/..._entegrasyon.php?wsdl'. The encoding in the declaration 'ISO-8859-1' does not match the encoding of the document 'utf-8'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with the 'Generate code from a WSDL file' method.

1. I've created .net framework console app and I've added Service Reference normally way (**Add-> Service Reference... -> Enter Address -> Go -> Ok**). Thanks to this, I got a wsdl file.
2. As a second step, in my .net core project, as usual
   **Add-> Service Reference... -> Connected Services -> Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider**  but this time we are choosing **Browse**, not **Go** and instead of enter wsdl url, we select wsdl file.

Thanks to below post for reminding me to add references from wsdl file.

https://medium.com/grensesnittet/integrating-with-soap-web-services-in-net-core-adebfad173fb